# Re-arranging pointers in a struct doesn't give me the correct result

Tags: c

I have this `struct`

```
typedef struct InfoSession {
    TabNodePtr FirstTab;
    TabNodePtr LastTab;
    TabNodePtr CurrTab;
    TabNodePtr AuxTab;
    char *OpeningAddress;
} InfoSession;
```

which has to be a browser session that controls all its tabs. The `OpeningAddress` is the default address when opening a new tab.

My `main` looks like this:

```
int main() {
    InfoSessionPtr  MySession1 = NULL, MySession2 = NULL, CurrSession = NULL;
    int option, flag, n;
    char *OpeningAddress == NULL;
    ...
}
```

When I want to change the `OpeningAddres`s using this function:

```
void SessionNewOpeningAddress(InfoSessionPtr Session, char *OpeningAddress1) {
    Session->OpeningAddress = OpeningAddress1;
}
```

everything works fine and the new opening address I add is displayed correctly. But, when I have two sessions at the same time, changing the `OpeningAddress` of the second session also changes the `OpeningAddress` of the first session (When adding a second session, after I've inserted a new `OpeningAddress` to the first session, the `OpeningAddress` of the second session isn't the same as the first session).

For example, if I change the opening address of the first session to `"AA"`, adding a new session after that makes the `OpeningAddress` of the second session to be `NULL`, and not `"AA"` (Which is what I want).

Adding the new session(s):

```
            if (MySession1 == NULL && MySession2 == NULL) {
                MySession1 = SessionNew(OpeningAddress);
                CurrSession = MySession1;
                printf("\nNew Session (first) created!\n");
                printf("First Session assigned as 'Current' Session\n");
            } else {
                MySession2 = SessionNew(OpeningAddress);
                CurrSession = MySession2;
                printf("\nA Session already exists, created a second one.\n");
                printf("Second Session assigned as 'Current' Session\n");
            }
```

Changing the opening address:

```
        printf("\nInsert the new Opening Address:\n");
        scanf("%s", OpeningAddress);
        SessionNewOpeningAddress(CurrSession, OpeningAddress);
```

Also, the code changing which session to manage:

```
            printf("\nPress 1 to manage first Session or 2 to manage second Session:\n");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            getchar();
            if (n == 1){
                CurrSession = MySession1;
                printf("\nManaging first Session\n");
            } else if (n == 2){
                CurrSession = MySession2;
                printf("\nManaging second Session\n");
            }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @stefnto Could you do some digging and see if there's anywhere that you are assigning the same pointer to both objects? Or at least show us where `OpeningAddress` is set up in your code before the key piece of code?

Comment: @xing that's what I think as well that is happening, and here comes my understanding about pointers, when I declare `char *OpeningAddress` I declare a pointer to a string which points to NULL, so the line `Session->OpeningAddress = OpeningAddress ` will assign the address to the "OpeningAddress" of the session, thus when inserting a new opening address a new string with a different starting address is assigned to the OpeningAddress variable that has been declared in main, leaving the previous attached address to "OpeningAddress" of the session unchanged. Is my thinking correct or not?

Comment: You think a quick fix would be to declare 2 `char *OpeningAddress1` and `char *OpeningAddress2` one for each session?

Comment: A line like `char *OpeningAddress == NULL;` does nothing. Why are you *comparing* to `NULL`?

Comment: @tadman it was supposed to be one '=', wrote two by mistake.

Comment: Easy to mess up. It's just something worth fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple:

- the call `SessionNewOpeningAddress(CurrSession, OpeningAddress);` sets the `OpeningAddress` member of the `CurrSession` to point to an array in the caller's scope that gets overwritten after this call. Indeed all `OpeningAddress` fields may point to the same array in the calling function.
- posting code fragments as you did is not helpful, much of the context is missing and some other code might cause the problem.
- hiding pointers behind typedefs as in `TabNodePtr` is highly discouraged. It leads to confusing code for beginners and advanced programmers alike.

To fix your problem, you could make a copy of the string:

```
#include <string.h>

void SessionNewOpeningAddress(InfoSessionPtr Session, char *OpeningAddress1) {
    Session->OpeningAddress = OpeningAddress1 ? strdup(OpeningAddress1) : NULL;
}
```

You would need to free the previous value as long as the structure has been initialized properly, and also free the current `Session->OpeningAddress` when the structure is discarded.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I make this change I get a segmentation fault when trying to run the function.

Comment: @chqrile I didn't point `char *OpeningAddress=NULL` and no segmentation fault popped, thanks for the help!